# Updating a large file in a Docker container

Tags: docker, api, swagger

I currently have a set of applications running in separate Docker containers. The containers themselves are running on the Cloud. Sometimes, a configuration update is necessary. The configuration update requires me to send a file that is 300 - 500 MB in size.  I am wondering what would be the best practice to do this.

The containers each have a Swagger doc exposed, so I could expose an endpoint to potentially load the file in.  Would I send the contents of the files via the request body in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think exposing an endpoint and uploading an entire file to the server is a great idea both due to Network and Security issues.

Currently, I do not have any idea about what those update files are, but by your approach container will be doing double work. (Doing its own job + downloading updates)

For copying the updated files you use a secure protocol like `scp` from local to the docker container. now assuming you have backups of update files in case of network failure while copying updates then this approach works.

Here is a little better strategy.

1. Ideally all your update files should be hosted on docker host which is then mounted using volume to docker container
2. Better way will be you should upload this update file to a cloud storage service that is highly scalable.
3. Your storage trigger will hit an endpoint which will start downloading the update file to your docker host
4. post successful download you can restart your container which will pick the latest update from the docker host

So to conclude you will have an endpoint outside Docker that download updates for you and handle the logic of starting/stopping the container with the correct update version.

Also not to mention it will be great to have a backup of previous updates which will help in case of a faulty update. You can use a rolling update file writer kind of mechanism for this.

This approach is great both in terms of Network and Security aspects.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So just to recap, I'd ideally want to spin up a blob storage on the Cloud, mount that as a volume to my container, and set a watchdog to identify when there is a new file updated.  If so, download that file and update the config.  Is that correct?

Comment: Little correction in that. this can be even simpler. 1. not any blob to be particular we can use any storage service. i.e. s3 on aws. 2. no, mount your host's file system as volume. 3. no need to set up a watchdog its an overkill, usually on the cloud storage services they give you a trigger kind of setup (more like hook) that can do certain actions for you including an HTTP request... let's say download this file action from your docker host.

Comment: In my case, the container will be deployed on an App Service in Azure, so it would not have a host file system unfortunately.  So I was thinking of somehow connecting the App Service to the storage service.

Comment: Sure we can do that then. Actually, this is really subjective thing. we just discussed overall architecture. and yes please accept the answer if this helped you. Thanks.